# Asp.Net Core - Returns 500 for no reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to ask for help with this weird behaviour.

I have Asp.Net Core (.Net Core version 2.0) application, which runs without problems on my Windows 10 machine, but when I publish it to Debian server, it starts acting weird. I've verified files, the sha1 of application that works on Windows is the same as sha1 of application that acts weird on Debian.

It has multiple controllers with no views - they work without problem (I just return ObjectResult from them). And I have one controller that uses View and whenever I try to call it on Debian server, it returns 500 Internal Server Error without any information - just empty response. I tried uploading debug version to the server, i tried encapsulating the controller methods into try-catch, but everything is still the same -> empty 500 response.

Summary:

```
+------------+----------+----------+
|            | Windows  | Debian   |
+------------+----------+----------+
| Controller | OK       | OK       |
| w/o view   |          |          |
|            |          |          |
| Controller | OK       | 500 Err  |
| with view  |          |          |
+------------+----------+----------+
```

No error message, try-catch doesn't do anything, debug mode doesn't do anything.

Here is log: https://pastebin.com/22AC8d4G
The funny thing is, that I HAVE Form.cshtml in /View/HouseForm : http://prntscr.com/jytj0f - and I tried to put it in /View/Shared as well. It works on Windows, but doesn't work on Debian. Probably .Net Core issue?

If you need any additional information, leave a comment and I'll edit this question.

Comment: What are log outputs? you could enable console logging. it should print the reason.

Comment: I added log to the question and it honestly looks like .Net Core issue. It says that the view isn't there, but it IS there. It works on Windows, but not on Debian. Maybe issue with linux filesystem?

Comment: On Linux file names are case sensitive. Check that on views and controllers file and class names.

Comment: Please show the controller and the view. Show the returned error 500. Here normally it shows which line threw the exception

Comment: Ahh, I have it! The initial directory path was different - in Windows, it was one level above the /Views folder. But in Linux, it was two levels above /Views folder.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin already solved, but thank you. And it didn't show any information, just empty response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the problem:

As shown in the log, Asp couldn't find the view file. It worked on Windows, because on Windows, startup path was set one level above the /Views folder. But on Debian, startup path was set two levels above the /Views folder. So I had to add this to Program:

```
        if (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().EndsWith("3step"))
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "publish"));
```

Comment: The startup path is set to the current working directory. you should only ever deploy the contents of the publish folder and use it as working directory for `dotnet yourapp.dll`